# Xamarin android Read Contacts and Numbers

Tags: android, c#-4.0, xamarin.android

I know to retrieve the names of contacts that's code below. But what should I change in this code to also have the numbers of phone associated with the contact list?

```
  var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;

            string[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
   ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName };

            var cursor = ManagedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);

            var contactList = new List<string>();

            if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    String phoneNumber = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number));

                contactList.Add(cursor.GetString(
                        cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1])));
            } while (cursor.MoveToNext());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question while I recently wrote a similar code. The only thing you need in order to retrieve phone numbers, is to:

1. Make another query to Uri
   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri;
2. Set projection to include ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number; and
3. Select based on id, i.e. selection parameter should include "_id = " +
   contactId

Your query should look like this:

```
string[] projection = { ontactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number };
string selection = "_id = " + contactId;

var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri, projection, selection, null, null);
```

This query will bring you phone numbers for a contact id but in code below, due to performance issues, I just made one call for all phone numbers and then assign each contract their numbers. Hope it helps.

```
private List<Contact> GetContactList()
{
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    string[] projection = {
                ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoUri
            };
    var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;
    ICursor cursor = ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            string id = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0]));
            string name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1]));
            string photoUri = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[2]));
            contacts.Add(new Contact() { Id = long.Parse(id), DisplayName = name, PhotoUri = photoUri });
        } while (cursor.MoveToNext());

        GetContactPhoneNumber(contacts);
    }

    return contacts;
}

private async void GetContactPhoneNumber(List<Contact> list)
{
    string[] projection =
        {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId
                };

    var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.Count > 0)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    string id = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1]));
                    string phoneNumber = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0]));
                    Contact contact = list.Where(c => c.Id == long.Parse(id)).FirstOrDefault();
                    contact.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
                }
                catch
                {
                }

            } while (cursor.MoveToNext());
            cursor.Close();
        });
    }
}
```